# Deleted /etc/mysql directory, can't run mysql

Tags: mysql

I have deleted **/etc/mysql directory accidentally** and now I can't run *mysql* command. Is there any way I can recover it?

Now, I am getting this error on running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2018-08-15 20:17:03 EDT; 9s ago
  Process: 4101 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: mysql.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 15 20:17:03 nullbyte systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
```

Answer (score 2):

Restore a backup.

That is not just the directory that holds your MySQL config but also certificates and the root password for recovery. Nobody is going to able to provide those for you except you.

Comment: How can I restore? I don't have any backup now.

Comment: I have posted the error @Rinzwind . Please check.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just do

```
sudo apt install --reinstall mysql-common
```

If that doesn't work, download `mysql-common.deb` from [here](https://packages.debian.org), choose the right version, open it with Archive Manager, and extract the directory from it. You may need to create a couple of symbolic links. On my system they are:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf -> /etc/alternatives/my.cnf
/etc/alternatives/my.cnf -> /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf (this link probably still exists)
```

although the latest versions of `mysql` come with a version of `mysql.cnf` in `/etc/mysql/conf.d`. So check what `/etc/alternatives/my.cnf` points to.

Comment: I am afraid this probably is not going to work. It might reset it to default but that will not be enough to cover alterations (and it is likely he needs those to be able to connect).

Comment: I was speculating that the default files would be enough to connect - of course, not if certificates are stored there.

Comment: @Jos kindly check. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

If no backup, too narrow chance to recover. Directory "/etc/mysql " have configuration files.Most important file is debian.cnf. Because it have system generated password.

Try to recover with scalpel.

https://www.howtoforge.com/recover-deleted-files-with-scalpel

If you failed to recover any one of the file.I am using mysql 5.7. If you are using same version just, replace debian.cnf and try.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fm8qxT92dAAF64xvMFQWI44XhsyokrW-/view?usp=sharing

The owner and group should be root.

All the best

Answer (score 0):

You can reinstall mysql completelly, as explained in this other post https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/27558

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1295487)